# Adding a constructor to a property of a 'parent' object

Tags: javascript

Is it ok to do this?

```
var MyObj = function() {};
var MyObj.prototype.thing = function() {};

MyObj.SubObj = function() {}
MyObj.SubObj.prototype.thing = function() {}

var ins = new MyObj();

var another = new MyObj.SubObj();
```

In this code MyObj acts like a parent class because I've assigned MyObj.SubObj to be another constructor function with it's own prototype chain.

Is it ok to nest a constructor off of another constructor like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly *okay* to do it, but it doesn't do anything special. In particular, there's no kind of inheritance relationship between `MyObj` and `MyObj.subobj`, nor are the `MyObj.prototype.thing` and `MyObj.subobj.prototype.thing` functions in any way linked.

I also wouldn't call it *nesting*. The only relationship here is that `subobj` is a property of the function `MyObj`. It's not nested within it in any kind of scope way...

But it's perfectly fine to do it, as an organizational thing (for instance, to avoid lots of global symbols), provided inheritance isn't meant to be implied.

---

Side note: The *overwhelming* convention in JavaScript is that constructor functions like these use initially-capped `CamelCasing`, to distinguish them from normal functions (using non-capped `camelCasing`). Earlier you had `myobj` and `subobj`. You've changed the first to `MyObj`, but if following this convention, you'd change `subobj` to `SubObj` as well (just FWIW).

Comment: Thanks! Yes I understand that they're not linked or nested. That's what I'm after -  I was trying to limit global objects as you mentioned. I've updated the title of the post to reflect this.